# Undefined local variable or method `searchkick'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick

I'm trying to add [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) to my Rails application. I'm following the exact instructions on the [Get started page](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#get-started) but I keep getting the following error:

```
Started GET "/airports" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-26 10:20:33 +0000
Processing by AirportsController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method `searchkick' for #<Class:0xb48f3ba8>):
  app/models/airport.rb:2:in `<class:Airport>'
  app/models/airport.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/airports_controller.rb:3:in `index'


  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (19.8ms)
```

Here's what the Airport model looks like:

```
# ./app/models/airport.rb
class Airport < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchkick
end
```

And this is what the Airport controller looks like:

```
# ./app/controllers/airports_controller/rb
class AirportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @airports = Airport.all
  end
end
```

What's causing this?

Comment: Seems fine to me.Have you really installed `searchkick` gem in your machine?

Comment: Yes I did. I had to restart the server. All working now. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restart the server. The server has to be restarted after a change is made to the Gemfile.

Other things you can try if that doesn't work:

- add `gem 'searchkick'` to the Gemfile
- `bundle install`

Comment: I had to stop spring to get it to work for me ( `spring stop` ). Something else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. I checked `gem list`, searchkick was there.

But I deleted `searchkick` in Gemfile and runned `bundle install`. Then add `searchkick` and `bundle install` again, it works well:)